# RegWrite returning ErrorLevel 1

Tags: autohotkey

Platform and settings:

AutoHotkey_L Unicode x86 1.1.13.0

RegView=Default

64-bit OS (W7)

32-bit script

Hi Folks,

The following line of code is returning ErrorLevel=1:

RegWrite,REG_DWORD,HKLM,SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System,PromptOnSecureDesktop,0

When I modify the registry manually, it works fine. Btw, the RegWrite fails in the same way with the ANSI x86 binary (I haven't tried the Unicode x64 binary). Anyone know why the RegWrite is failing? Thanks, Joe

Comment: Maybe it's because you need to run it [with admin rights](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/46526-run-as-administrator-xpvista7-a-isadmin-params-lib/?p=311068).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The manipulation of registry entries usually postulates administrator privileges, which, as of WIN Vista or later must be acquired explicitely, if UAC wasn't turned off.
For AHK, call the following function ([source](http://www.autohotkey.net/~shajul/Projects/RunAsAdmin.ahk)):

```
RunAsAdmin() {
  Loop, %0%  ; For each parameter:
    {
      param := %A_Index%  ; Fetch the contents of the variable whose name is contained in A_Index.
      params .= A_Space . param
    }
  ShellExecute := A_IsUnicode ? "shell32\ShellExecute":"shell32\ShellExecuteA"

  if not A_IsAdmin
  {
      If A_IsCompiled
         DllCall(ShellExecute, uint, 0, str, "RunAs", str, A_ScriptFullPath, str, params , str, A_WorkingDir, int, 1)
      Else
         DllCall(ShellExecute, uint, 0, str, "RunAs", str, A_AhkPath, str, """" . A_ScriptFullPath . """" . A_Space . params, str, A_WorkingDir, int, 1)
      ExitApp
  }
}
```

Comment: I found that code yesterday after your tip, but I don't understand what it's doing. I found numerous references to it (including the earlier version that didn't work with compiled scripts or passed params), so I'm sure it works, but I haven't found anything that explains it. I'd like to understand it before using it in scripts. Any advice for that? Thanks, Joe

Comment: @user2829469 This script basically calls the Windows API functions `ShellExecute` or `ShellExecuteA` respectively, depending on your AHK version. The parameter `"RunAs"` is kind of a trick to elevate UAC privileges. The other parameters should be pretty straight forward, specifying the path to the executable and optionally the start arguments the script received in the first place. Check out [ShellExecute in the Win API docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: MCL,
I'll take a look at the ShellExecute doc and get back to you if I have any questions. Thanks much, Joe

Comment: @user2829469 If my answer solves your problem, please consider accepting it. This way, others will know you don't need help anymore. If you have follow up questions about elevating privileges, post them as new question(s) here on SO.

Comment: I had been looking for a way to do that earlier, but didn't see it. I much prefer the previous site that AHK used for the forum...this Stack Overflow site is horrible. In any case, I see the up and down arrows (not at all clear what they do) and the check-mark, which I'm guessing accepts that comment as the answer, but it appears on only one of your comments, so it's not at all obvious how to accept another answer. I'm involved in LOTS of forums with many different approaches to the site...this is by far the worst. Anyway, I'll click the check-mark and will see what happens. Regards, Joe

Comment: On top of that, it seems that a comment can be only 600 characters (I noticed that I had just 6 left on the last post). That's nowhere near enough for a technical forum. Not good to force the poster into multiple comments to get the point across. I wonder why the AHK forum was moved here.